# Can I use Spotlight to search for files by name?

Tags: macos, spotlight

My most common search pattern is to search for files based on their name. When I try this in Spotlight (`cmd-space`) it rarely works. Is there a way to make Spotlight search for file names, and to place those results on top?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this in your search to search for files with 'query' in their name: **`name:query`**

For more info about Spotlight commands, you can take a look at an [excerpt](http://hints.macworld.com/dlfiles/spotlight_cmds.pdf) of [Mac OS X: The Missing Manual](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596153298/).

Answer (score 4):

Spotlight needs you to search using the **name:** selector to restrict the results.

[image: name:index.html in spotlight]

I've also become a big fan of the [Found](https://www.foundapp.com/) app. It's currently free on the [app store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/found/id527134927?mt=12) and lightning fast (seems faster than LaunchBar to me - and that's saying a lot as it's a speed demon). It's real claim to fame is that it also indexes DropBox, Gmail, Google Drive and Google Docs.

---

Back to spotlight if you don't want another app no matter how robust, slim and fast.  Since the spotlight window defaults to showing everything - not just limited to searching the file name, I like to open the Finder search window and click on name. For me it's quicker than using the **name:img** trick since I get more hits than the spotlight window itself will show and end up hitting the show all results more often than not.

<kbd>option</kbd> +<kbd>command</kbd> +<kbd>space</kbd> and then you can type the name you wish to find followed by a click on the `File Name` button will only show the results with that string in the file name.

[image: Search Window]

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. Before I was able to search for `filename.txt`, but in Catalina that no longer works. It does work if I search for just `filename` without the extension. However, `name:filename.txt` still works.

Comment: This still works for me - thanks for [asking a new question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/393341/cant-search-exact-file-name-with-extension-in-catalina-spotlight) @GeneParcellano