# Can you search Filenames in Spotlight as opposed to all metadata and contents by default?

Tags: macos, spotlight, search

I understand there is a dropdown menu in the spotlight search to select "Filenames"  in spotlight, but is there a way to make this your default when searching?

Answer (score 2):

Apple has search keys, so it's not changing a default, but it does let you specify file names (here they would contain the string "**test**"):

```
name:test
```

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204014
- [Can I use Spotlight to search for files by name?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12029/)
- https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/12056/5472 has a picture of entering this quite a few versions back - so here's a newer screen image of this in practice.

[image]