# Can't search exact file name, with extension, in Catalina Spotlight

Tags: catalina, spotlight, search

I used to be able to launch Spotlight (command + spacebar) then search for `filename.txt`, but in Catalina, that no longer works. However, if I search for just the `filename` that will show some results, and I'd have to pick out the right one.

Ideally, if I search for the exact file name (`filename.txt`) it should show me the exact file if it exists.

How do I re-enable the behavior that allows me to search using the full file name with extension?

Comment: This works for me on Catalina 10.15.5 - 19F101 - are you sure this isn't just your spotlight index being corrupt as opposed to an intentional change in the operating system? I can make arbitrarily named files with foo.txt and bar.foo and they show up instantly in spotlight. Same with your filename.txt. Would you be open to an answer that explains how to run a live search on command line to find a problem with spotlight?

Comment: @bmike Hi Mike, that might be the case. I've tried reindexing before to no avail. I'm open to trying out other methods. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In addition to rebuilding the index, I've also tried rebuilding the LaunchServices databases to no avail. The odd thing is that searching for `filename.txt` works in Finder search, but not Spotlight.